# SQL Server 2005 Database Mail Resends Historic Messages following SP4 Build 5324

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent, database-mail

I have applied SP4 Build 5324 to a SQL Server 2005 Enterprise active/passive cluster (Build pathway: 4053 to 5000 to 5324).

The SQL Server log contains zero errors.

The SQL Server Agent log contains the following records continuously written since the Build was completed:

1. [LOG] Unable to read local eventlog (reason: The event log file is
   corrupted)
2. [LOG] Successfully re-opened the local eventlog - NOTE: Some events
   may have been missed

Email messages that are marked with dates days and months prior to applying SP4 Build 5324 were subsequently resent [edit] **hundreds of times** [/edit] ("storm" would be an apt description).

[update] I've confirmed that there were zero unsent items (sysmail_faileditems and sysmail_unsentitems views) prior to applying the service packs. [/update]

If you have encountered this behavior, I would appreciate learning if you identified the cause.

Thank you.

PS: Yes, it is *well* past the time to upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server. Let's leave that discussion for another day. ;-)

Comment: Do you have other systems to upgrade? I mean there was obviously some glitch, perhaps those e-mails were never actually sent, or for some reason were still sitting in unsent, and the restart triggered them. But getting the actual reason, how would it help you? It's not like you can recall the e-mails like they never happened.

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand. If "upgrade" refers to the SP4 Build 5324, then, no: the only other SQL Server 2005 instance (Standard) was upgraded at the same time (4035-->5000-->5324, rather than 4053-->5000-->5324) without incident. I've also learned that the Application Event Log is corrupt.

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand. I'd like to know the cause in case this is a persistent issue. I've currently turned database mail services off.

Comment: I'd suggest you open a support case, but I don't that will work out very well since 2005 has long been out of mainstream support.